# launch_app() alternative in Appium for Python

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I am performing mobile automation on a real device. With [Appium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appium) 2.0, I was facing issues while launching the app, so I was using the `launch_app()` method to hard launch it every time I ran it.

But with the latest [Appium-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/) (v3.0.0) `launch_app()` method has been [deprecated](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/15807).

And without `launch_app()`, my app rarely launches. Below is my code for reference.

```py
class MyAPP:
    @log
    def __init__(self,device_name:str=DEVICE_NAME, environment:str=DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT)->None:
        self.environment                                           = environment
        envPackage                                                 = '.staging' if environment=="Staging" else ''
        desiredCapabilities                                        = {}
        desiredCapabilities["appium:deviceName"]                   = device_name
        desiredCapabilities["appium:automationName"]               = AUTOMATION_NAME
        desiredCapabilities["appium:platformName"]                 = PLATFORM_NAME
        desiredCapabilities["appium:platformVersion"]              = ANDROID_VERSION
        desiredCapabilities["appium:appPackage"]                   = f'{APP_PACKAGE}{envPackage}' #APP_PACKAGE
        desiredCapabilities["appium:appActivity"]                  = APP_ACTIVITY
        desiredCapabilities["appium:instrumentApp"]                = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages"]      = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:nativeWebScreenshot"]          = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:newCommandTimeout"]            = NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT
        desiredCapabilities["appium:connectHardwareKeyboard"]      = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:noReset"]                      = True
        options = UiAutomator2Options()
        options.load_capabilities(desiredCapabilities)

        # starting session based on set capabilities
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(SERVER_URL, options=options)
        
        # hard launch app 
        self.driver.launch_app()    #### deprecated
```

I tried to go through the documentation, but I did not get anything. How can I fix it?

Comment: I got my question answered in Appium Discussion forum. Refer [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/launch-app-alternative-in-appium-python-client-v3-0-0/40472)

Answer (score 0):

You can just try with:

```
self.driver.startActivity(".appPackage", ".appActivity")
```

It will bring your app to the main thread.

Comment: According to [docs](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/) start_activity() is the method in python. But i get the following error:
```AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'start_activity'```

Comment: [This](https://discuss.appium.io/t/launch-app-alternative-in-appium-python-client-v3-0-0/40472) answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

With Appium-Python-Client v3.0.0, you can use the following code:

```
import logging
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.uiautomator2 import UiAutomator2Options

class MyAPP:
    @logging.log
    def __init__(self, device_name: str=DEVICE_NAME, environment: str=DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT)->None:
        self.environment = environment
        envPackage = '.staging' if environment=="Staging" else ''
        desiredCapabilities = {}
        desiredCapabilities["appium:deviceName"] = device_name
        desiredCapabilities["appium:automationName"] = AUTOMATION_NAME
        desiredCapabilities["appium:platformName"] = PLATFORM_NAME
        desiredCapabilities["appium:platformVersion"] = ANDROID_VERSION
        desiredCapabilities["appium:appPackage"] = f'{APP_PACKAGE}{envPackage}' #APP_PACKAGE
        desiredCapabilities["appium:appActivity"] = APP_ACTIVITY
        desiredCapabilities["appium:instrumentApp"] = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages"] = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:nativeWebScreenshot"] = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:newCommandTimeout"] = NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT
        desiredCapabilities["appium:connectHardwareKeyboard"] = True
        desiredCapabilities["appium:noReset"] = True
        options = UiAutomator2Options()
        options.load_capabilities(desiredCapabilities)

        # Starting session based on set capabilities
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(SERVER_URL, options=options)

        # Start the app
        self.driver.start_activity(desiredCapabilities["appium:appPackage"], desiredCapabilities["appium:appActivity"])
```

The main change is to use the *start_activity()* method instead of the *launch_app()* method. The *start_activity()* method is the new recommended way to start an app in Appium-Python-Client v3.0.0.