# Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'launch_app'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest, appium-android

I am working with Appium Android, but I keep getting into this error message.

**E       AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'launch_app'**

The same problem occurs with close()
**
Below is my conftest.py file**

```
import pytest
import allure
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

appium_server = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"

desired_cap = {

    # Emulator - Android
    "deviceName": "Nexus 4 API 30",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "11.0",
    "udid": "emulator-5554",
    "appPackage": "com.epf.mip.uat",
    "appActivity": "com.epf.mip.uat.MainActivity"
}

# Converts capabilities to AppiumOptions instance
capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_cap)

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep


@pytest.fixture()
def appium_android_driver(request):
    print("Initializing Appium Android Driver")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server, options=capabilities_options)

    yield driver

    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="Screen Before Error",  attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)

    driver.quit()
```

**Below are my test code:**

```
def __init__(self, appium_android_driver):
    self.driver = appium_android_driver

def launching_iAkaun_Application(driver):
    driver.launch_app()
    .
    .
```

**Below are the main code :**
import pytest
from appium.webdriver.appium_service import AppiumService
appium_service = AppiumService()

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("appium_android_driver")
class TestSuite_EPF_Android_App:

    def test_initialAppLaunch(self, appium_android_driver):

        launching_iAkaun_Application(self.driver)
```

I am using Selenium 4.14.0, pytest 7.4.3, Appium Python Client 3.1.0

I need the launch_app for closing and reopening the driver. So that I can call the test cases from excel.

Answer (score 0):

Appium v3 doesn't have the `launch_app()` method. You can see on [the PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/) the following message:

---

**Quick migration guide from v2 to v3**

- Replacement

  - `launch_app`, `close_app` and `reset` methods: Please refer to https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/15807

---

So I would suggest you look at the linked GitHub page, but it looks pretty long and unclear to me, so instead try [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77248549/1198321).

Comment: I manage to launch the app via self.driver.startActivity(".appPackage", ".appActivity"), but now have problem to close the driver. I need it to launch and close the driver for different test cases. How to close the driver?

Comment: Have you tried `terminateApp`?